# Eclipse in auto build loop using m2e with git-commit-id-plugin to generate resource

Tags: eclipse, m2e

I'm using Eclipse (tried both Juno and Kepler) with `m2e`. Everything works fine until I tried to use `git-commit-id-plugin` to generate a property(`git.properties`) file of my git build (branch name, tag name, build time, etc).  Here's the directory hierarchy.

```
.classpath
.project
.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
pom.xml
src/git.properties (Generated file)
```

I think the issue here is auto build in `eclipse/m2e` will generate `git.properties`. After that, since `git.properties` is updated, it will trigger another auto build.

Is there a way to tell eclipse not to "watch" `src/git.properties`?

All the file mentioned above is attached below:

**.classpath**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
        <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
                <attributes>
                        <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
                </attributes>
        </classpathentry>
        <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

**.project**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
        <name>testMavenEclipseAutoBuild</name>
        <comment></comment>
        <projects>
        </projects>
        <buildSpec>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
                <buildCommand>
                        <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
                        <arguments>
                        </arguments>
                </buildCommand>
        </buildSpec>
        <natures>
                <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
                <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
        </natures>
</projectDescription>
```

**.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs**

```
eclipse.preferences.version=1
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.inlineJsrBytecode=enabled
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.targetPlatform=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.codegen.unusedLocal=preserve
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.compliance=1.6
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.lineNumber=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.localVariable=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.debug.sourceFile=generate
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.assertIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enumIdentifier=error
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.forbiddenReference=warning
org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.source=1.6
```

**.settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs**

```
activeProfiles=
eclipse.preferences.version=1
resolveWorkspaceProjects=true
version=1
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>testMavenEclipseAutoBuild</groupId>
        <artifactId>testMavenEclipseAutoBuild</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>test</name>
        <build>
                <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
                <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.6</source>
                                        <target>1.6</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                        <plugin>
                                <!-- Ref: https://github.com/ktoso/maven-git-commit-id-plugin#using-the-plugin -->
                                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>2.1.10</version>
                                <executions>
                                        <execution>
                                                <goals>
                                                        <goal>revision</goal>
                                                </goals>
                                        </execution>
                                </executions>

                                <configuration>
                                        <generateGitPropertiesFile>true</generateGitPropertiesFile>
                                        <generateGitPropertiesFilename>src/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
                                </configuration>

                        </plugin>
                </plugins>
        </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project, select `Properties/Resource/Resource Filter` and add an Exclude All rule to exclude the file `git.properties` from the resources.

That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to modify generateGitPropertiesFilename so git.properties will be generated in target/classes directory.

```
<generateGitPropertiesFilename>${project.build.outputDirectory}/git.properties</generateGitPropertiesFilename>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the eclipse lifecycle-mapping-metadata.

See section 4.2 on [this site.](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html)

Add the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lifecycleMappingMetadata>
    <pluginExecutions>
        <pluginExecution>
            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                <groupId>pl.project13.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>git-commit-id-plugin</artifactId>
                <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
                <goals>
                    <goal>revision</goal>
                </goals>
            </pluginExecutionFilter>
            <action>
                <execute />
            </action>
        </pluginExecution>
    </pluginExecutions>
</lifecycleMappingMetadata>
```